# Upload file to a server with jquery and java

Tags: java, jquery, file, model-view-controller

Im doing a webapp to upload files to a server.

I have this form in my view:

```
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
        <input id="send" value="Upload" type="button" />
    </form>
</body>
```

And i send the file with jquery and ajax:

```
var form = new FormData();
    form.append('file', $("#file")[0].files[0]);


    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/UploadMotion/upload',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: form,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Funciono");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Fallo");
        }
    });
```

The jquery looks like correct, because the value of the file is sent correctly in the form var.

I send this data to my controller, but I'm not receiving the correct file. I'm receiving a temporal file, with this format:

```
...\...\AppData\Local\Temp\upload_c72334c_14b9858dd1d__8000_00000004.tmp
```

This is the code of the controller:

```
public Render upload(File file) throws IOException{



    String folderName = "C:\\Users\\Inma\\Documents\\MisDescargas";
    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String fileName = folderName+ File.separator + token;

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

    IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();

    return renderJSON("token",token);


}
```

I use webmotion, a framework to develop web applications.

This is the mapping file:

```
[config]
   package.views=WEB-INF/views
   package.actions=com.vincle.actions


[actions]
   GET       /                      view:index.jsp
   POST         /upload                MainController.upload
   GET          /download              MainController.download
```

The networks screen shows this: http://postimg.org/image/lguc3q1ex/

When I try to create the FileInputStream to copy this file to my server, I get the exception FileNotFound exception, because this file doesn't exist.

What is the problem? Why don't I recieve the correct file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you see in Network how is it going in the request ? How exactly are you reading this `file` on server side ?

Comment: Also provide server side java code.

Comment: Do you have the file in MisDescargas?

Comment: can you upload the snapshot again with your network -> you call -> Request tab -> Form parameters ?

Comment: MisDescargas is the directory where i will save the file.  The problem is that in the variable file i am receiving a wrong file. Then, in the line when i build the FileInputStream, i get a exception (FileNotFoundException)

Comment: Try changing `$("#file")[0].files[0]` to `document.getElementById('file').files[0]`

Comment: What snapshot do you refer? This?http://postimg.org/image/ou1a3n1pt/

Comment: can you add your `mapping` file in resources folder to your question ?

Comment: can you upload the image for full stack trace as the error one is missing few lines at the bottom specially the lines after `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: I just deployed the sample `uploadmotion` and I'm seeing that the file not found exception is in fact  in `download` method which is called right after your upload is complete :) In that code it's looking for the file that you just created but instead of your custom path it's looking in some temp directory, so change the `folderName` in `download()` to point to `C:\\Users\\Inma\\Documents\\MisDescargas`.

Comment: These are the snapshoot of the stack trace: http://postimg.org/image/dbf964hvp/ http://postimg.org/image/xdcg0bvff/

Comment: Excuse-me, but the file not found exception is in upload method. The problem is that in the upload method, i am receiving a wrong file,no te file that i want to upload and that I select in my view. Instead, i receive C:\Users\Inma\AppData\Local\Temp\upload__556001e5_14b98ffbb30__8000_00000001.tmp, and it doesn't exists. I don't call to download method anywhere, You can see that in the ajax call, if the petition has success, i only show a alert message.

Comment: Hmm.. The stack trace screenshot is not showing all the lines. Like I asked earlier, upload a new one with lines after FileNotFoundException, thats the key here :-)

Comment: Yes, this screenshoot http://postimg.org/image/dbf964hvp/ shows all the FileNotFoundException trace. I have tried with other files, and it worked! It's very strange, If I create a new file, for example New->TxtFile, and afterthat I try to upload it, this fails...but whit other file that i have in my pc, it works. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Cool :) Simple text files are failing for you ?